# Angular2/Nativescript: Issues with default text color when using the Nativescript core dark theme

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using the Nativescript core dark theme for the first time and running into some issues...  when I add a Textfield the placeholder text is very dark and almost impossible to read, the same goes for the entered text on the textfield...  When I add a label I have the same issue, the only work around i've found is to apply class="text-primary" on a label to make it readable...  Am I missing something?  Shouldn't the text on the dark theme be lighter when the background is dark?  Any idea what I can do to fix this (if it's not supposed to be this way)?  right now all I can think of is applying additional styles on every text element which might take a long time...

Answer (score 0):

It should take a single line to change the default style of all TextFieds in your app(or Label elements, or TextView elements)
e.g

open **app.css** and declare a custom default style for the element

```
Label {
  color: red;
}
```

The styles in app.css will be applied n all files from your app and will be overwritten only if you apply a CSS style for the same CSS property at sub-level.

Comment: Why would the core dark theme have such dark text by default though?